# Need to move a common Method to another class and called it from different class in c#

Tags: c#, .net, class, object, methods

Below are the list of classes. These classes have a common method whose objective is same in classes. I want to remove the repetation of CommonMethod() by moving this method to Fourth Class and get it called from remaining Other class

```
    Class First
{
    string ClassField
    method FirstClassMethodOne()
    {
      CommonMethod()
    }

    method CommonMethod()
    {
        classField = 1  
    }

}


Class Second
{
    method SecondClassMethodOne()
    {
      CommonMethod()
    }

    method CommonMethod()
    {

        Fifth.classField = 1        
    }

}


Class Third
{
    method ThirdClassMethodOne()
    {
      CommonMethod()
    }

    method CommonMethod(string a, string b)
    {
        stirng ClassField
        classField = 1      
    }

}


Class Fourth
{
    string FourtClassField
    method FourtClassMethodOne()
    {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can move the method to a new class and make the 3 old classes inherit from that new class.

```
class BaseClass
{
   public void YourMethod()
   {
     // ...
   }
}

class FirstClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

Comment: Thanks Zdravko for your response. Can you please glimpse over what i have written inside CommonMethod().  classField = 1 is defined in different way.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a static class with the method inside. That method could accept some parameter to distinguish between the classes if needed.

Answer (score 1):

You could move the method into `Fourth` and call it via:

```
  public class Fourth() {
         public void Method() {

         }
  }

  var fourth = new Fourth();
  fourth.Method();
```

Or you can make an base / abstract class and inherit from that.

```
 public class Base {
      public void CommonMethod() { }
 }

 public class First : Base
 {

 }

 public class Second : Base
 {

 }

 var first = new First();
 first.CommonMethod();

 var second = new Second();
 second.CommonMethod();
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a new class and add `CommonMethod()` to that class. It looks like you have overloaded versions of `CommonMethod()` so you'll need to account for different parameters in each of your overloaded methods. You will need an instance of your class or a static class for calling your method from each individual class.

Answer (score 0):

If your classes all inherit the common base ClassBase, then leaving the method in ClassBase would be appropriate.

```
class ClassBase
{
    public static string ClassField;

    public virtual void MethodOne()
    {
        CommonMethod();
    }

    public virtual void CommonMethod()
    {
        ClassField = "1";
    }
}

class ClassOne : ClassBase
{
}

class ClassTwo : ClassBase
{
    public void CommonMethod(string a, string b)
    {
        string localVariable;
        base.CommonMethod();
    }
}
```